# going to gym and workout with thin or fat body - which is better?

Tags: gym, bellyfat

Basically My **hands and shoulders** looks **thin** and I have **lot more belly** fat.

I want to make my hands and shoulders fat and want to reduce belly.

Usually i eat **2/3 times rice** in a day , less amount of **fruits** and 100 gm of **chicken** per week . I dont drink **milk** . and almost no **junk foods**  no **chocolates** and **sweets.** But i eat curd a lot in a day.

I dont do any **workout, running** but 90 minutes **walk** per day

i am **26** years old with **6.1** tall , about **171 punds/78 kg**.

1)If i **workout in gy**m, than i need to **eat more food**, than again my belly will become increase again.

or 2) may i **workout in gym** and **eat less** - is that fine ?

or 3) may i first reduce my complete belly and get some fat on hands and shoulders , than should i go to gym to get better results ?

Please give me some suggestions what procedures i need to follow ?

Comment: @gwaigh Thanks for comment, but really this question is completely different , its not about `reduce fat on specific area of body` , but its all about `going to gym with thin or fat body - which will give better results`......

Comment: You have asked a half dozen questions centered around the faulty premise that you can target the fat on your belly - whether certain actions add to it or reduce it.

Comment: @gwaigh if i ask all things in same question , than that question will be closed as `Too broad` . I dont think there is no wrong in asking too many questions... i am sure it will help lot of users in future.....

Comment: @USer345738380: The issue with multiple questions in the same question is that you can have just as many correct answers, each addressing different points, including answers which answer some parts correctly and others incorrectly. That said, this was closed as a Duplicate because, as noted, this all centers around a premise that one can target weight loss or weight gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you can't target fat loss, you can't target fat gain. However, making regions of your body bigger ***can be targeted doing specific exercises to add muscle.***

Adding muscle will ***also help you lose fat*** by increasing your resting metabolic rate. Think of this as the number of calories your body burns at rest. For example:

- A lean, **muscular** body builder may burn 4000 calories per day (by doing nothing).
- A lean model **(with little muscle)** may only burn 1500
  calories per day (by doing nothing)

---

> **Consider what's required by your body to build muscle**

- Proper diet is required to build muscle.  You need enough protein and carbohydrates and fats to fuel and enhance recovery from your workouts.
- You also need rest and recovery time between workouts to allow your body to rebuild and increase your muscle mass.
- You don’t grow muscle during your workout - but rather between workouts.

---

> **Think of these resources like a bucket of water**

- The more often the bucket is full - the faster you're able to gain muscle mass.
- The emptier the bucket - the harder it is to build more muscle.

*For each strength training workout you perform:*

- You take a scoop of water out of the bucket. The harder you train, the bigger the scoop of water you take from the
  bucket.

*As you replenish your muscle-building and energy supplies* by resting and eating effectively - you assure that you have all the necessary resources necessary to build muscle.  In other words:

- You refill the bucket

*The problem with doing 90 minutes of cardio* is that you draw on the same resources that you have available to build muscle. In other words:

- You take more scoops out of your bucket.

That not only means fewer resources that are available for building muscle, but because your recovery is also compromised.

- It becomes even harder to refill the bucket.

---

***That doesn’t mean you can’t do any cardio while building muscle***. It just means that you need to perform cardio that minimally impacts the resources necessary to build muscle - such as shorter, more intense forms of cardio.

Comment: `The more often the bucket is full - the faster you're able to gain muscle mass.
The emptier the bucket - the harder it is to build more muscle.` is it means if `i am fat, i can build muscle easily` ?

Comment: Think of the “bucket” as the ACTIVE or currently available FUEL your body has to build muscle (food you eat today) such as the protein from a shake you drink after a workout. Current fat is the INACTIVE or storage form of excess FUEL from foods you've eaten in the past.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your goals, but since your are skinny fat I would recommend eating less and losing weight first.

1) Start off by eating less and going to the gym. If you wish to build muscle, increase the amount of protein you eat. Since you are a beginner you should be able to burn fat and build muscle at the same time by eating less calories but increasing protein.

2) refer to 1

3) This depends on your goals, but like I said above you can gain muscle and lose fat at the same time if you haven't worked out before.